Can you cast a non-cantrip spell using your action, and make a bonus action melee spell attack on the same turn?
To clarify: I am using the 5e Binder class presented in the Complete Binder book from MageHandPress.
The class has (what I believe is classified as an ability) "Minor Spirits" which can grant certain bonuses or actions. It reads as follows:
Minor Spirits

Beginning at 2nd level, you can use the runoff energy
from your binding ritual to enlist two minor spirits to
your service, selected from the Minor Spirits list. These
spirits manifest faintly around you, though you can
cause them to become invisible or return to visibility
once on each of your turns (no action required).
You can bind additional spirits to your service as
you gain additional levels in this class, as shown on the
Binder table. When you gain a level in this class, you
can choose to replace a minor spirit enlisted to you
with another.

And one of those spirits reads:
Totem

A totem is a manifestation of an animal spirit. As a
bonus action, you can make a melee spell attack with
the totem’s bite against a target within 5 feet of you,
dealing 1d8 piercing damage on a hit.

My question is: Can I cast a non-cantrip spell such as "Magic Missile" with my action, and then make a bonus action "melee spell attack" with the "Totem" spirit?
I know there's a rule about not being able to cast two spells in the same turn, but I don't know if this falls under that. If the bonus attack is considered an ability and not a spell, I should be able to, right?

The Totem melee spell attack is not casting a spell.
The bonus action casting rule states:

A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven’t already taken a bonus action this turn. You can’t cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

The restriction only applies to actually casting spells. A class feature that calls for a melee spell attack is not casting a spell, so the bonus action casting rule is simply not in view here.

As a way of illustrating the difference between casting a spell and making a melee spell attack, you might reference another game feature that includes both.  For example, casting the the arcane hand spell once permits you to make a melee spell attack once per turn, for the next ten turns, including the turn you cast it.  The spell can be counterspelled, the attacks cannot.
